# Coloring of a knot diagram by a trivial quandle

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants

Suppose a knot diagram is colored by a trivial quandle $T_n$ of order $n$ (The trivial quandle $T_n$ is a finite set of order n with the binary operation $x*y=x$ for all $x,y \in T_n$ ). My question is: Is it necessary that $n=1$ in which case we say that the coloring is trivial? Or we can find a non-trivial coloring of a knot diagram by a trivial quandle?

Answer (score 1):

I will assume you mean to say that the coloring uses every element of $T_n$.  Colorings don't need to be surjective in general.

For links, no; for knots, yes.

For a link: consider the Hopf link. It's fundamental quandle is $T_2$.

For a knot: choose a diagram.  Follow the knot around, labeling the strands $A_1,A_2,...,A_k$ (so $A_i$ and $A_{i+1}$ are opposite each other as understrands at a crossing).  Let $a_1,\dots,a_n\in T_n$ be the corresponding colors.  The relationship for a knot quandle is $a_i*a_j=a_{i+1}$ at a crossing with $A_j$ the overstrand and $A_i,A_{i+1}$ the understrands. The quandle is trivial so $a_i=a_{i+1}$. Hence, knots can only be colored surjectively by $T_1$.

Comment: Is it true that for knots, the coloring function is surjective? How about figure eight knot? It’s colored by the dihedral quandle of order five and only four colors are used for each non-trivial colorings.

Comment: The definition of a knot coloring by $Q$ is a quandle map from the fundamental knot quandle to $Q$.  The definition does not require surjectivity (which is what I meant by my second sentence).  Simple counterexample: every quandle $Q$ can be augmented with a copy of the trivial quandle to get a quandle $Q'$, and with respect to $Q'$ the knot coloring is no longer surjective.

Comment: As for the figure eight knot, even though not all five colors appear, it is still considered to be surjective.  This is because the fifth color appears after some number of Reidemeister moves of the knot diagram.  A coloring is for a knot, not a knot diagram.

Comment: @KyleMiller Another way of saying it: although you can take the quandle $Q = Q_{4_1}$ of the figure eight to be generated by the four arcs of a diagram (with the crossing relations), and therefore any coloring (= quandle homorphism) from $Q$ to another quandle $C$ is _determined_ by its values on those four arcs, it is not necessarily the case that the _image_ of the homomorphism is just the image of the four arcs. Indeed, if we color $4_1$ by $Q$ itself via the identity, then the four arcs map to just the four generators of $Q$ but the image is infinite: all of $Q$.